# Show UIPopover in center of screen in both rotation

Tags: ios, popover

I have requirement to show setting page in center of screen for both rotation whenever rotation gets changed. I used way to show popover to show my Settings page (`UITableViewController`). But I am not able to show my popover in center of screen area. Is it another way that I can show my settings page in center of screen. Please note that my settings page have next pages or screens also so I have to use `NavigationController`. I didn't find anyway to show `UITableVIewController` or `NavigationController` directly other than putting them in `PopoverController`. If any more detail/clarification is required then let me know. Note that I am showing popover without any arrow style.

Answer (score 3):

Instead using an `UIPopover`, present the new view controller modally using

```
modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
```

Comment: If I present UINavigationController from existing UIViewController as mentioned above then I am not able to have custom size of UINavigationController and its children. I need square screen needs to be displayed in center which has multiple sub screen which needs to be displayed in stack style (hence I need to use UINavigationController)

Comment: Sorry it is working fine. I have used another style by mistake